# git: Do repositories tend to naturally bloat? And what are good practices to alleviate that

Tags: git, version-control, repository

If I understand correctly, a git repo contains all revisions.
Cloning a repo retrieves all revisions.
Therefore, if one particular revision contained a lot of files (let's say too much), this error is "enshrined" into the repo and carried around by all contributors?

Is there a way to "cut off" a certain point in the repo timeline, beforewhich the revision is assumed as obsolete and not needed to be copied around everywhere?

The only way I can think of is to archive the current repo and start a fresh one with the leading edge of the current repo

Comment: It depends if those revisions are part of the history of the branches you care about or not. If they are, there's nothing you can do unless you rewrite history (there are several ways to achieve that, depends on what exactly you want  to do). However, if they are part of branches you don't care about, you can simply delete those branches and run `git gc`, eventually the relevant objects that take up space but are not part of any existing branches' history will be discarded

Comment: @Omer: also, `git gc` will be called automatically by Git in huge repositories. It occurred several times to me.

Comment: Also it's also worth mentioning that it's also called automatically by Git hosts such as GitHub,  GitLab etc.  so deleting the branches there and recloning after a while should probably work as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use shallow clones to only get the top x commits, and thus much less data to transfer:

```
git clone --depth 1
```

Comment: Also consider `--shallow-since` if your Git version has it. That's a lot easier to use in general than trying to guess a good depth.